# how to tell which COM objects to pass and which not to pass to Marshal.ReleaseComObject?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, com-interop

My understanding has been that any time you use a .net interop COM object, you have to call Marshal.ReleaseComObject which decreases the reference count by 1 which ensures that the memory used by the Com object is released after the reference count hits 0.

That said, consider the following sample code, taken from a VS add-in project:

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
{
  DTE2 _dte = (DTE2)application;

  Events e = _dte.Events;

  for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
  {
    e = _dte.Events;
  }

  Console.WriteLine(Marshal.ReleaseComObject(e));//100
```

But if I were to do,

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
{
  DTE2 _dte = (DTE2)application;

  CommandBar commandBar = ((CommandBars)_dte.CommandBars)["MenuBar"];
  CommandBarControls ctrls = commandBar.Controls;

  for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
  {
    ctrls = commandBar.Controls;
  }
  Console.WriteLine(Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctrls));//0
}
```

So in both cases, the code calls a property that returns a "Com Object" multiple times, but it looks like the reference count does not increase, as I would have expected, in the second example.

Can someone explain the above behavior ?

Comment: Read [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx).  The "silent assasin" section brings the point home pretty well.